# How to invoke a SignalR Core hub method from Postman/WebSocket King

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a SignalR Core hub. I can connect to the same hub using clients like Postman or WebSocket King. But, I am unable to invoke a hub method that expects parameters. The same method can be easily invoked from SignalR JS client. I inspected browser developer tools and extracted the message getting transferred from client to server. When I try to invoke the same method from Postman/WebSocket King with the same message it just don't work.

Hub method:

```
public async Task Subscribe(string[] imeis, string group)
{
   ...     
}
```

Message getting transferred from SignalR client (accessed from browser developer tools):

```
{"arguments":[[10001001],"ALL"],"invocationId":"0","streamIds":[],"target":"Subscribe","type":1}
```

From Postman/WebSocket King, sending this same message does not hit the hub method. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should make the properties name match the name in method, try to send transferred  message instead

Comment: @JerryCai Transferred message means? Can you elaborate please.

Comment: If you want to post to method, you should pass imeis and group, the message can not match the properties(imeis and group) now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so for my case, I think I've been able to connect to the server. So basically, it is a 2-step process:

**1. Establishing connection**

Issue an HTTP POST request to: ***<SIGNALR_CORE_SERVER_HUB_URL>**/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1*

The response should be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 256
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2021 09:08:59 GMT

{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"TP- 
KX7BpPj4y4rxMFwaznw","connectionToken":"OeGB- 
EKkoYvcSg7Z4p4n0w","availableTransports": 
[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}, 
{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
```

The connection token value (**OeGB-EKkoYvcSg7Z4p4n0w**) is important here! Save it for use in Step 2.

**2. Invoking SignalR hub method:**

Using WebSocket protocol, invoke the URL:***<SIGNALR_CORE_SERVER_HUB_URL>**?id=OeGB-EKkoYvcSg7Z4p4n0w*

After successful connection establishment, pass in the following data to server through websocket:

```
{"protocol":"json","version":1}
```

This will result in getting an empty response from server.
Following this, invoke the server hub method and pass the arguments as follows:

```
{"arguments":[["10001001"],"ALL"],"invocationId":"0","streamIds": 
[],"target":"Subscribe","type":1}
```

Here, "Subscribe" is my SignalR Core Hub method name, which accepts two arguments, an array of strings (["10001001"]) and a string ("ALL").

After this, from server side, push notifications will start coming to client through the same websocket connection.